# Execute composite component code only when it is displayed

Tags: java, jsf, primefaces, dialog

I have a JSF composite component inside a PrimeFaces dialog that has `dynamic`=true(*dynamic* - enables lazy loading of the content with ajax). The component is initialized inside the overriden `encodeBegin` method. This happens when the dialog is displayed.

If I remove the dynamic attribute, encodeBegin method is called also when the dialog is not displayed and breaks existing code.

Is it possible to execute composite component code only when the dialog is displayed?

Here is a code selection:

```
<p:dialog id="actionsDialog"
    widgetVar="actionsDialogWidget" resizable="false" width="800"
    height="600" showEffect="fade" hideEffect="fade" modal="true">
    <h:form id="confirmationWizardForm">
        <acme:actionWizard name="wizard" widgetVar="wiz" bean="#{accountsBean}"
            header="#{accountsBean.entityHeader}"
            update="form:genericAccounts" onClose="actionsDialogWidget.hide()" />
    </h:form>
</p:dialog>

...

<p:commandButton value="Add"
    action="#{accountsBean.initializeEntity}" process="@this"
    update=":actionsDialog" oncomplete="actionsDialogWidget.show()">
```

Comment: When the dialog is not displayed do you set `visible' or `rendered` to false?

Comment: No. I don't have any attribute that controls the rendering of the dialog.

Comment: so you control it's visibility on the client side?

Comment: Yes. PrimeFaces dialog exposes two methods: `show` and `hide`(ex: actionsDialogWidget.show()).

Answer (score 2):

The problem is that you are controlling the visibility from the client side, which means that the markup for the dialog gets generated but remains hidden by css rules.

This can be noticed for  example analysing the primefaces [dialog showcase](http://www.primefaces.org/showcase/ui/dialog.jsf) - there, the dialog is hidden until you press "Basic" command button, but the HTML `<div id="basicDialog"...` is there all the time, even if the dialog window is not visible.

If the dialog gets rendered, so does the content - there's no stopping this without dynamic content loding.

Adding the dynamic attribute changes the behaviour as ajax is used to fetch the dialog (along with its content) when it get's displayed.